# Ionic App v1 - updating Ionic Framework Version (not Ionic CLI)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, bower

I'm trying to understand how to update my Ionic Framework Version.

```
ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS:
Node Version: v6.9.1
```

So the current Ionic Framework Version is "1.1.0"

I updated my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello-ionic",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.3"
  }
}
```

and run `bower install`

but the new files are being stored at 'bower_components' folder

My folder structure:

[image]

I also copied the files from 'bower_components' to 'lib' folder and still after `ionic info` the 'Ionic Framework Version' is still '1.1.0'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
npm install -g ionic@1.3.3
```

After the CLI has been updated you have a few options when it comes to updating your base library install, goto the root of your project and run this command:

```
ionic lib update
```

[Here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/updating-ionic-framework-project-cli/) for more details. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the project to the new versions:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
npm install ionic-angular@3.7.0 --save
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@3.0.0 --save-dev
npm install @angular/core@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/common@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/compiler@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/forms@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/http@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.3 --save
npm install rxjs@5.4.3 --save
npm install zone.js@0.8.17 --save
```

In addition to improving `ionic-angular 3.x`.

Also, if you're using animations, run the command:

```
npm install @angular/animations@4.4.3 --save
```

It looks like you might actually want

```
npm update packagename
```

which does try to honor semver, and does recursively update all the dependencies of packagename. Of course, it does them all recursively asynchronously at once.

If you can give up the need for updating deps-of-deps, then you can get pretty far with

```
npm --depth 0 update grunt
```

After a research:

> npm will correctly handle version conflicts between shared
>   dependencies by downloading the correct one for each. So, if Dep A
>   depends on Dep C v1.0.0 and Dep B depends on Dep C v2.0.0, they will
>   each be installed and used appropriately. Therefore, you are free to
>   install the latest of any packages you would like.

Then, feel free to update update package by package or use (AFTER UPDATE YOUR ANGULAR PACKAGES) and exclude for a while the `ionic packages` from the `packages.json` to don't update them:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I would like to upgrade to Ionic Framework Version 1.3.3. The issue is that thw lib folder remain without any change

Comment: Then, try with npm install -g ionic@1.3.3 instead of ionic@latest

Comment: It will install it in node_modules but the lib folder will remain the same

Comment: Thanks, but it just updated the ionic CLI, what I need is to automatically update the lib folder with ionic framework

Comment: @OronBen-David - what was the solution to this?  My `Ionic-CLI = 6.10.1`, but my `Framework =  Ionic1 1.0.0` - doing the `npm -g ionic@1.3.3` is for the CLI.  Like you, I need to update the Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate version of IONIC v1 is `1.3.5`, I guess.
You'd better make a global install of `ionic`, first.

`sudo npm i -g ionic`

Then, install new **Ionic v1 CLI Utility** locally for CLI commands as it has been released for v1 project maintenance.

`npm i @ionic/v1-toolkit`

Answer (score 0):

try command: npm install -g cordova ionic.

Answer (score 0):

simple run

```
ionic lib update
```

See official [Docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli#update-ionic-lib)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct only on updating ionic version with experience I can say you might have old dependencies which might crash with your upgrade so best is to use, https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates after installing the package run `npx npm-check-updates` this will recommend and update all your packages to latest stable.